# Hash Map key check in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Need help.I have a hash map which is returned from a spring controller to JSP.Is there a way just to check if a certain key exists irrespective of any value(the value may be null too)

Say,  the below hash map is being sent from the controller

```
HashMap hmap = new HashMap();
hmap.put("COUNTRY", "X");
hmap.put("REGION", null);
```

If the key REGION exists ( value may be anything including null) then display some section in the jsp.

I am trying to access the key as ${hmap['REGION']}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

try using containsKey:

```
${hmap.containsKey('REGION')}
```

Comment: @Amz - In order to invoke the map's containsKey() or containsValue() methods, then you need to ensure that you're running a Servlet 3.0 compatible container like Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, JBoss AS 6, etc and that your web.xml is declared conform Servlet 3.0. This way you can utilize a new EL 2.2 feature: invoking non-getter methods with arguments.

Comment: if you don't have a new version of tomcat you can use the fn:containsKey(map,key) from the functions taglib

Comment: @EdgeCaseBerg Eh? fn:containsKey? Never heard of this JSTL function! https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html

Answer (score 4):

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${hmap }" varStatus="status">        
      <c:if test="${entry.key == 'REGION'}">
        <tr>
           <td>${entry.key}</td>
           <td>${entry.value}</td>
        </tr>
      </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Check this, if this solution works or not ?
And post if not working and also post your JSP's jstl code.

Comment: Thank you ,I am trying to access the key as ${hmap['REGION']}

Comment: `${hmap['REGION']}` should work. How you are `sending the HashMap`, check that `HashMap received on JSP` or not ?

Comment: Why on earth would you use a loop?

Comment: @EJP - I think that OP ll iterate the hashmap and if condition match it ll show data otherwise not. What's strange in that ? On earth still yet does anyone haven'r use loop in jstl ?

Comment: @user3145373ツ : I have the data of the map in the JSP.I am looking for a check where I am trying to identify if the key exist.

Comment: @Amz : ok then there are 2 ways, one is to check like a said or second one is other answer given by the : Vipul Paralikar.

Answer (score 3):

I know that you want to test for where the value may include null, but there's a solution by using the `empty` operator that is elegant when one might want to also exclude null values in that it will evaluate to `true` if the value is null or does not exist.

```
<c:if test="${not empty hmap['REGION']}">
    <%-- conditional block --%>
</c:if>
```